# Redundant 'if' statement less

Tags: if-statement, kotlin

My code is as below

```
 private fun validateInput(): Boolean {
     if (etReportRow1.text.toString() == "" 
         || etReportRow2.text.toString() == "" 
         || etReportRow3.text.toString() == "")
         return false
     else
         return true
 }
```

The compiler tell me

> Redundant 'if' statement less... (Ctrl+F1)  This inspection reports if
>   statements which can be simplified to single statements. For example: 
>   if (foo()) {    return true } else {    return false } can be
>   simplified to return foo().

Won't the suggested code go into loop?

Comment: u can just return !(etReportRow1.text.toString() == "" || etReportRow2.text.toString() == "" || etReportRow3.text.toString() == "")

Comment: BTW, avoid using `==` for object (strings) comparison

Comment: @MauricePerry this is a kotlin question, which overrides the `equals()` with `==`, so this will work fine

Comment: @Lino thanks, I misread the question; sorry about that

Comment: @MauricePerry if we wouldn't make mistakes, we wouldn't be able to improve ;)

Comment: @Lino ... and we wouldn't need a website like stackoverflow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All statments in the form:

```
if(condition){
    return false
} else {
    return true
}
```

can be simplified into:

```
return !condition
```

So in your case it would lead to:

```
return !(etReportRow1.text.toString() == "" || etReportRow2.text.toString() == "" || etReportRow3.text.toString() == "")
```

Or:

```
return 
    etReportRow1.text.toString().isNotEmpty() && 
    etReportRow2.text.toString().isNotEmpty() && 
    etReportRow3.text.toString().isNotEmpty()
```

Note: the `isNotEmpty()` is an extension method:

```
public inline fun CharSequence.isNotEmpty(): Boolean = length > 0
```

To avoid duplicate code you could also use a `Sequence`:

```
public fun validateInput() = sequenceOf(etReportRow1, etReportRow2, etReportRow3)
    .map { it.text.toString() }
    .all { it.isNotEmpty() }
```

Answer (score 5):

Because a boolean expression evaluates to a boolean value, you can simply return the result of the expression itself, without having to explicitly return `true` or `false`.

You can further simplify things using the following single-expression function:

```
 private fun validateInput() = etReportRow1.text.toString() != "" && 
                               etReportRow2.text.toString() != "" &&
                               etReportRow3.text.toString() != ""
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
return !(etReportRow1.text.toString() == "" || etReportRow2.text.toString() == "" || etReportRow3.text.toString() == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
private fun validateInput() = !(etReportRow1.text.toString.isEmpty()  
                                || etReportRow2.text.toString().isEmpty()
                                || etReportRow3.text.toString().isEmpty() )
```

Answer (score 0):

Even more concise:

```
public fun validateInput() = setOf(
    etReportRow1, etReportRow2, etReportRow3
).none { 
    "${it.text}".isEmpty() 
}
```